# how to reverse a string using array of pointers?

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc

I want to reverse a string(user gives at runtime) using array of pointers,malloc and not by using array of characters. Can anybody help me by giving me a code? I am very new to C. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This makes no sense. A string is an array of characters. I don't see how an array of pointers would help with reversing a string.

Comment: @Blaze Technically, a string is a null-terminated *sequence* of characters. It does not have to be an array.

Comment: why you need array of pointers to reverse a single string? two character pointers are enough

Comment: Besides. Read [ask]. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking, But the following program meets your conditions,
1. there is array of pointers 
2. there is malloc 
3. there is no character array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STR_MAX_SIZE 256

int main()
{
    char *str;
    char *pos[2];
    char c;

    if((str = malloc(STR_MAX_SIZE)) ==NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    scanf("%s",str);

    pos[0] = str;
    pos[1] = str;
    while(*pos[1]) {
        pos[1]++;
    }
    pos[1] -= 1;

    while(pos[0] < pos[1]) {
        c = *pos[0];
        *pos[0] = *pos[1];
        *pos[1] = c;
        pos[0]++;
        pos[1]--;
    }
    printf("reversed : %s\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a doubt. why did you use pos[2]? And if I want to track whether the pointer got right memory location or the memory block is full, then how to track it? sorry for these childish doubts.

Comment: why did you use pos[2]? becoz u said , program should use array of pointers